# How to use DisplayTemplates in MVC core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0, display-templates

I used to use `DisplayTemplates` in MVC5 to get rid off `foreach` loops from views

If I have a `ProductDto` and `ProductController`

I would place a `ProductDto.cshtml` under

> Views/Product/DisplayTemplates/

or

> Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/

to use the template for list of products: I would replace the `foreach` loops with the following line to list all products by using the template: `@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.Products);`

And if I want to use same model (`ProductDto`) in a different display template for instance let's say `ProductDtoPrintView` then I would create another template under `Views/Product/DisplayTemplates/` with name `ProductDtoPrintView.cshtml` and pass the `templateName` as 
`@Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.Products,"ProductDtoPrintView")`.

But this does not seem to work in MVC Core 2.0

I can only get one template working for each model. And templateName does not seem to have any impact at all.

My testing:

When `ProductDto.cshtml` is placed under `Views/Product/DisplayTemplates/`

If I have only one display template for `ProductDto` model then the `templateName` really doesn't seem to have any impact. It works with any name or without name.

`@Html.DisplayFor(x =>x.Products)` -- works
`@Html.DisplayFor(x =>x.Products,"")` -- works
`@Html.DisplayFor(x =>x.Products,"whatever")` -- works

But when I add another display template for the same Model as `ProductDtoPrintView.cshtml`

Then things get screwed a bit.

`@Html.DisplayFor(x =>x.Products)` --works

`@Html.DisplayFor(x =>x.Products,"")` --works

`@Html.DisplayFor(x =>x.Products,"")` --works

`@Html.DisplayFor(x =>x.Product, "ProductDtoPrintView")` --doesn't work 500 internal server error.

`@Html.DisplayFor(x =>x.Products, "ProductDto")` --doesnt work - 500 error

`@Html.DisplayFor(x =>x.Products, "DisplayTemplates/ProductDto")` --works and returns `ProductDto.cshtml` template

`@Html.DisplayFor(x =>x.Products, "DisplayTemplates/ProductDtoWhatever")` --works and returns `ProductDto.cshtml` template

`@Html.DisplayFor(x =>x.Products, "DisplayTemplates/ProductDtoPrintView")` --works and returns `ProductDto.cshtml` template

Basically no way I can get the ProductDtoPrintView working unless if I delete `ProductDto.cshtml` file.

Anyone experiences the same problem?  and how excatly this DisplayTemplates are supposed to work in MVC Core?

Comment: a custom taghelper would be the more favored way of doing that in asp.net core, displayfor is mainly backward compat